# How do i transform a list to str so my SQL query can use the values?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to insert several values in my Query for SQL, but I need the list to be in str to be able to insert, the problem is that when I convert it to str it changes its form.

this is a example:
I get the values I need to insert in my query from:

```
values = list(table.id)
values
[5, 2, 3, 4]
```

but I cant insert it unless is a str

but when I convert it to str

```
str(values)
```

it shows like this:

```
'0     5\n1    2\n2    3\n3    4\nName: id, dtype: int32'
```

needs to look like this without the brackets

```
5, 2, 3, 4
```

Thanks

Comment: you can try `", ".join(map(str, [5, 2, 3, 4]))`

Comment: Values doesn't look like a list. If it were, you could just do `str(values)[1:-1]`. If it isn't a list, do what Andres just said.

Comment: Andres, still shows the brackets after applying this, 101arrows, still looks like '0 5\n1 2\n2 3\n3 4\nName: id, dtype: int32', when applying yours

Answer (score 3):

As explained in the comments, thanks to `101arrowz`:

```
values = [5, 2, 3, 4]
print(str(values)[1:-1])
```

**Output**

> 5, 2, 3, 4

Comment: Please do not forget to mark it as answer if possible. You are welcome!

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: There is an upvote button near the answer showing zero. If you click up arrow you upvote it and right below the down arrow, it might be a check mark, if you click on it you recognize it as answered.